# выпадающий текст

Tags: java, android

Просьба навести на реализацию такой штуки - есть список (ListView) хочется по нажатию на элемент списка, что-бы он расширялся вниз и вместе в котором он расширился появился нужный мне текст (что-то на подобии ExpandableListView, а может оно мне и надо).

Answer (score 2):

собственно [тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/expandablelistview.php) и есть ответ на мой вопрос, нужно использовать ExpandableListView